# make every function of a file start with the same call to an external function

Tags: python

I'll give a bit of context but I don't think you need to know about flask to understand my question.

I have a file (`flask_app.py`) and I would like all the functions (except the one handling the welcome page) to start with the call to the function `verify()`, more precisely those four lines (but it doesn't really matter what those lines are):

```
if verify():
    pass
else:
    return redirect("/")
```

`redirect("/")` should redirect the user to the welcome page if `verify` returns `False`. Again, it's not central.

It's however a little bit awkward to copy and paste these 4 lines everywhere in my code. I know I can make a one-liner out of it but this is still repeating one line in every function of my code. **So my question is: is there any way to do this automatically? (*a magic something I could write in Python at the beginning of the file to make all functions (except one, but I could just put it in another file to be fair) defined in this given file start by those 4 lines*).**

Comment: That code ought to be `if not verify(): return redirect("/")`

Comment: Look at Python [function decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/) or Flask [middleware](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/patterns/viewdecorators/).

Comment: No, you'll have to do this yourself

Comment: Thanks @jarmod for the two references, they are crystal clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This runs either myfunc or redirect depending on the return value of verified. Note: To test this, change verified return value to True or False.

```
def verified():
    print('verified')
    return False

def redirect():
    print('redirect')

def verify(func):
    if verified():
        return func
    else:
        return redirect


@verify
def myfunc():
    print('myfunc')
myfunc()
```